# Python memory usage for large numpy array in repeated function call

Tags: python, arrays, memory

I wrote a function in Python that returns a large 2d numpy array `(2**13,2**13)`, call it pdd.

import pdd

array=pdd.function(some stuff)

If I call the function once the memory usage jumps to a few gigabytes. Then if I run the same command again
array=pdd.function(some stuff)
The memory usage roughly doubles, like its a second array of that size rather than just rewriting the concurrent one. The problem with this is I want to use this function with an mcmc sampler so many repeated calls to the function, which obviously can't work as it is.

So is there some way to free the memory, or something in the function to optimize or minimize the usage??

**EDIT**

I appear to have fixed the problem. After trying several things it seems to be scipy's fault. Inside the function there are several 2d FFTs and I was using scipy's fftpack fft2 and ifft2. This resulted in the creation of some large arrays using lots of memory that left/added over a gb in memory with each function call. When I switched to using numpys fft2 and ifft2 it went away. Now after the function ends in left with my one array with a few hundred Mb of memory and no more added with subsequent function calls.

I don't know or understand why this is, and found it surprising that numpy would be better in this case than scipy but there it is.

Comment: Are there still references to the original array hanging around?

Comment: Definitely use the smallest numeric type you can get away with by calling `dtype=type` in your array constructor (or follow the constructor with `.astype(type)`. I find myself needing unsigned bytes pretty often: `np.uint8`

Comment: you definitely have some leftover references (likely in pdd.function) however because ((2^13)^2)*4(bytes/ single float) = roughly 256MB. and numpy in my experience has near perfect byte for byte memory scaling (with a small overhead)

Comment: @mgilson I'm not sure what you mean. I can have just the one line that calls the function and stores the output in array. Then run the same line again and the memory roughly doubles. Not sure if it's to do with the output in the main code or something wrong in the function itself leaving memory around.

Comment: @mgilson likely leftover refs are in your pdd module

Comment: perhaps this sounds dumb but how to i get rid of leftover refs? Maybe I'm unclear on what that officially means (obviously I'm fairly new to this) Is there some way to list the variables that are still taking up memory? - and if in pdd function I'm performing operations on an array is it better to assign it to new variables or overwrite olds ones i.e. x=x+exp(y) then x=x^2, or x1=x+exp(y) then x2=x^2 ?